# C++ Linker Error on CppUnit

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, gcc, cppunit, occi

I'm trying to compile an extension library for CppUnit.

But it gives me the following error while linking:

`DatabaseAssert.cp:(.text+0x782): undefined reference to 'CppUnit::DatabaseAssert::getDBConnection(DBAdapter*)'`

The included header file has the definition :

`static oracle::occi::Connection* getDBConnection(DBAdapter *dbAdapter);`

Any clues why I am still getting the `undefined reference` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in the header is the function declaration, not its definition.
The linker is complaining because it cannot find the definition of the function which is probably in the library file which you did not link.

Link the library to your project.